# Maxxing out the trader track in Stone Age: Style is the Goal

Tags: stone-age

While playing a game of [Stone Age](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34635/stone-age) with the [Style is the Goal](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/107576/stone-age-style-is-the-goal) expansion, we had a player achieve ten traders on the trader track. Later in the game, she purchased a card which gave a +1 on the trader track. It wasn't clear to us whether she should receive the usual two decoration even though she couldn't move her counter on the track itself.

We settled on a house rule that yes, you could indeed take two decorations even if you can't advance any further on the trader track. This seemed to me like a reasonable decision as you are purchasing more traders, which would bring in decorations, even though the track itself maxes out at ten.

Has anyone else run up against this question and come to a resolution? I'd love to hear it if so, as I really enjoy playing Stone Age! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually a difference between the wording of the English and German rules, that I think is significant.  The English rules say:

> (Each time the player moves his marker forward  on the trader track,
>   regardless of how far, he takes 2 decorations.)

In the German, by contrast:

> (Jedes Mal, wenn der Spieler auf der Händlerleiste vorrückt, unabhängig
>   ob 1 oder 2 Felder, erhält er 2 Schmuck.)

To roughly translate that, and highlight the difference: "Each time that the player on the trader track advances, **regardless of whether it is 1 or 2 spaces**, he takes 2 decorations."

I think it's a lot clearer from that wording that getting the decorations is specifically linked to advancing along the track, and that "advancing 0 spaces" was not meant to count as advancing.  As such, I'd come to the opposite conclusion to user1873's answer, and assume that the designer only meant you to be able to get decorations while making real progress along the trader track, and not to be able to milk it for more decorations after having maxed it out.

Comment: Aha! That wording really does change how I see the rule. I appreciate you translating that here.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official clarification to my knowledge, so at least [you are not alone](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/814313/trader-movement-when-already-at-the-10-space) in this matter. A strict reading of the [rule book](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_398_gameRules.pdf), would lead me to the same conclusion you came to (emphasis mine).

> The player moves his marker on the trader track 2 spaces forward (and takes back his two figures). He also immediately takes two decorations. (Each time the player moves his marker forward on the trader track, **regardless of how far**, he takes two decorations.)

This all hinges on whether moving zero spaces is advancing your marker. I would contend that the rule would be to do as much as possible. The second statement of taking 2 decorations is independent of advancing your marker, so if you are at the top of the track you don't move the marker (still trading at 1:2), because you cannot, but you still collect decorations which you are able to do.

[No FAQ exists](http://www.riograndegames.com/games.html?id=398), and the [designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/928/bernd-brunnhofer)'s web[site](http://www.hans-im-glueck.de/stone-age-mit-stil-zum-ziel/) didn't appear to address the question. It did have a German copy of the rules, so anyone fluent in German who wishes to post a question to the designer or who can determine if the German rules are clearer on this matter are welcome to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue here, is that you don't get two Jewelry for moving on the track anytime, only when you take the Merchant action.

The rules for that specific card are clear.  You move 1 space on the track.  It says nothing about getting jewelry.  So, to give the same answer via a different route.  Nothing is gained.